Why can I switch the git branch without commiting the changes not stashing it?
When I'm working in a new feature in a branch, I'm asked to do something in another branch. So as usual I have to stash the changes or make a commit in order to be able the change the branch. But there are some cases where I can switch the branch without doing anything (Normally when the branch is new). I just want to know the reason behind this.
Thanks!

You can switch the branch if there are no conflicts.

Uncommitted changes do not belong to any branch. Therefore, you can take them with you when you switch to a different branch, but only when Git is able to do the switch without overwriting your changes.

This usually happens when the file you've modified also differs between those branches, and switching branches would require Git to extract the "another branch" version on top of your modified file – which would mean losing your uncommitted changes, so it refuses to do so (unless you force the operation).
(In theory it could try to stash/checkout/unstash automatically, like "git rebase" already does with its 'autostash' option, but doing so is essentially a whole 3-way merge and could lead to merge conflicts when applying the stash – i.e. there is no guarantee that it could switch the file to the new branch and correctly preserve your uncommitted changes, even more so in reverse.)
When the file is identical between both branches, it remains untouched when switching between branches and local changes can remain as they are.
